# I'm trying to check a form's input to make sure the fields aren't blank or contain specific words. Anyone know why this code isn't working?

Tags: php, forms

This is the "contactprocess.php" file that the form posts to:

```
$result = "";
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
if(($val != "") || (strpos($val,'http') == false) || (strpos($val,'seo') == false)){
$result = "clear" ;
}
}

if ($result == '') {
header("location: contact.php");
}
```

The code ignores the "header("location: contact.php");" line and continues on with the rest of the script. How else can this be written?

Comment: show your `$_POST` data by printing it out.

Answer (score 1):

In your if-branch where you attempt to redirect, you need `exit;` to prevent the script from continuing execution:

```
if ($result == '') 
{
   header("location: contact.php");
   exit;
}
```

Comment: While this is correct, I would also add that it is a really, *really* good idea to reform the `$result` IF clause as `if(empty($result))`